# Count rows in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to `while` loop information into a `SELECT` statement, then `COUNT` the results.  I have tried at least 10 different "solutions" and none works.  I only get 0, 1, or nothing.  Here's my most recent attempt:

```
$query35 = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE userID = $memberID";
$result35 = $db->query($query35);

while ($row35 = $result35->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $movie = $row35['movie'];

    $query36 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS similar FROM movies WHERE userID = '$profileID' && movie = '$movie'";
    $result36 = $db->query($query36);
    $row36->fetchObject;

    $similar = $row36['similar'];

    echo $similar;

}
```

Comment: What is `$profileID` is it same as `$memberID` ?

Comment: `$row35` is an array of all results from `$query35`. It is not a row. If you want a row, use fetch not fetchAll.

Comment: You should use prepared statements. If a user wrote a movie title (presuming thats what movie is) you could be injected by putting that value directly back into a query. Or better yet an actual example `Schindler's List `.. (not an injection example just a case where this would break)

Comment: This query pattern suffers form the N+1 problem and you should rewrite it to not make 1 query per movie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue

Comment: I don't see var `$profileID` declared anywhere, I guess you're getting empty results on your second query.

Comment: Why do a nested query/loop. Just do it in 1 query - `SELECT COUNT(*) AS similar FROM movies WHERE userID IN($memberID,$profileID) GROUP BY movie HAVING similar = 2`

Comment: I am trying to compare current user with profile they're viewing.  $profileID is the profile they're using and $memberID is logged in user.

Comment: @kainaw as I have mentioned, I've tried many solutions, including fetchAll.

Comment: @PedroLobito $profileID and $memberID our properly declared in another page.  For all intense purposes, assume they exist.  I know that isn't where my problem is.  I can echo them fine and get the id numbers.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor You can cut and paste random code from others, you will not likely get what you want. You must understand what you are doing. fetchAll works one and only one time. It returns an array indexed 0, 1, 2, 3... So, your attempt to access $row35['movie']; will be null because movie is not an index in the series 0, 1, 2, 3... So, you only hit on movies named ''. So, fetchAll clearly will not produce anything useful as your code is written. You need to change to fetch and then see what results you get for $row35['movie']. Then, work on the next query.

Comment: I wrote the code myself. This is simply one of many solutions I tried for my problem.  Regular php was so much easier when you could just count the rows and name it using `AS newName`.  Old simple way that doesn't work anymore... `$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM movies WHERE userID = '$userID'"; $result = mysql_query($query); $count = $row['count']; echo $count;`

Comment: And I have tried `fetch`.  I can echo the query fine.  If I echo $movie, it shows me all the correct instances and queries when I use fetch.  I have gotten the queries right in several of my attempts. Still isn't counting them

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking to do is count the number of times your loop is run per script execution, then it is fairly simple to do. See below:

```
$count = 0;

while($row35 = $result35->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //Do all your loop stuff.
    $count++;
}

var_dump($count);
```

**Important** to note that your $count variable needs to be declared outside of your loop.

Also you either need to use fetchAll with a foreach loop, or use fetch with a while loop, but don't mix them.

Also a tip on good practice. Try to avoid as much as possible executing any kind of database querying with a loop, you can run into serious performance issues down the line as your loops get bigger.

Comment: but `fetchAll` returns just once. isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't spot that. While fetch or foreach fetchAll, not any other combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row36->fetchObject;
```

Seems null object, I think it should be

```
$row36 = $result36->fetchObject();
```

Comment: Is there someone I can pay to write a code that works?  I've been working on this for 18 straight hours.  I've been through 75 solutions and none work.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor could you please put more specific requirements, such as database scheme, the scenario and result you're expected, etc

Comment: I am trying to create a compatibility feature on my website where it determines how many different interests you have in common.  This is just one table called movies where I am trying to return the number of results where the logged in member and the member of the profile the person is viewing have in common.

Comment: I'm trying to develop the site with as little money as possible but I'm seriously almost ready to go to odesk.com and pay someone to do it for me.  I can figure most things out myself, but this is the biggest headache of all.  So far my biggest challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you doing. But at least try:

```
$query35 = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE userID = $memberID";
$result35 = $db->query($query35);
if ($row35 = $result35->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
foreach ($row35 as $row) {

    print_r($row);

}
```

or maybe

```
$query35 = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE userID = $memberID";
$result35 = $db->query($query35);
while ($row = $result35->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    print_r($row);

    $movie = $row['movie'];

    $query36 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS similar FROM movies WHERE userID = '$profileID' && movie = '$movie'";
    $result36 = $db->query($query36);
    $obj  = $result36->fetchObject();

    $similar = $obj->similar;

    echo $similar;

}
```

Comment: Which question are you answering ? this one ?!

Comment: @PedroLobito I tried your "solution" and it found `fetch_assoc()` to be an undefined function.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor ohh, my bad, try fixed update  if you still need it

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm not where I can at the moment.  But if all you changed was fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)... don't worry.  Already tried that.  The result for that was that it counted each result individually, therefore all results were one and looped 3 times.  If only I could add up all the ones and get $similar to equal 3.